# Draw Venn diagram using Java

Tags: java, draw, boolean-logic, venn-diagram

I'm trying to draw a Venn diagram from a given boolean equation e.g  `(a AND b) AND c`
I want to do this on an android phone so I need to find a way to do it using Java.

I found a perfect widget that does everything I am looking for in this [Boolean Algebra Calculator](http://calculator.tutorvista.com/math/582/boolean-algebra-calculator.html#)

They create perfect diagrams, I am sure it's not using Java and neither could I see their logic.

I would appreciate any API, algorithm or guidance.

Comment: I am reminded of this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11337679/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses a WolframAlpha widget to generate the Venn diagram. Luckily for you, WolframAlpha offers [an API](http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/) for this kinda stuff.

Though I'll admit, it's a bit overkill. And you have to be connected to the internet to use it.

There are Venn diagram drawing solutions for Java such as [charts4j](http://code.google.com/p/charts4j/). But if you use those, you'll have to manually compute which regions are highlighted.

Comment: Yeah saw that widget, but I'm trying to find away to do it offline on an android phone. Is there away around that or an alternative ?

Comment: I doubt that there is a library that does exactly what you say given a boolean expression. You'll likely have to do the computation yourself and use a library to do the rendering.

Comment: I mentioned one in my answer.

Comment: Cheers mate, I guess its computation will not be an easy job.