# JButton and JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield, layout-manager

What's wrong? `ImageIcon` and the frame's size are working properly.
But the `JTextField` and the `JButton` aren't.

I need the solution.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Frame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Alkalmazás");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        JTextField field = new JTextField();
        field.setBounds(40,250, 300,35);

        JButton button = new JButton(new ImageIcon("table.png"));
        button.setBounds(40,400, 250,25);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tf.setText(""something);
            }
        });
        frame.add(field);
        frame.add(button);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't add both the `JTextField` and the `JButton` to the CENTER of the `JFrame`.  The `setVisible` method should be called last after all other methods.

Comment: Don't attempt to use setBounds(...).  Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. By default a JFrame uses a `BorderLayout`. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't mention what's "not working properly", but there are a few errors with your code:

1. Don't call your class `Frame`, it may confuse you or others about `java.awt.Frame`, something that may work would be `MyFrame`
2. Right now all your class is inside the `main` method and it's not placed inside the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), to fix this, create an instance of your class and call a method `createAndShowGUI` (or whatever you want to name it) inside `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`

   For Example:

   ```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MyFrame()::createAndShowGUI)
    }
   ```

   Or if using Java 7 or lower, use the code inside [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42404270/jcomponent-stops-getting-rendered-once-it-goes-off-the-screen/42404808#42404808) in point #2.
3. `setVisible(true)` should be the last line in your code, otherwise you may find some visual glitches that may be resolved until you move your mouse above your window or something that triggers the call to `repaint()` of your components.
4. Instead of calling `setSize(...)` directly, you should override `getPreferredSize(...)` of your `JPanel` and then call `pack()` on your `JFrame`, see this question and the answers in it: [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)
5. You're adding 2 components to the `CENTER` of `BorderLayout`, which is a `JFrame`'s default layout manager, there are other [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and you can combine them to make complex GUI's.
6. `setBounds(...)` might mean that you're using `null-layout`, which might seem like the easiest way to create complex layouts, however you will find yourself in situations like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42521097/2180785) if you take that approach, it's better to let Swing do the calculations for you while you use layout managers. For more, read: [Why is it frowned upon to use a null layout in Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing)

With all the above tips now in mind, you may have a code similar to this one:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MyFrame {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel pane;
    private JTextField field;
    private JButton button;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MyFrame()::createAndShowGUI);
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame("Alkalmazás");
        pane = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(100, 100);
            }
        };

        pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        field = new JTextField(10);
        button = new JButton("Click me");

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                field.setText("something");
            }
        });

        pane.add(field);
        pane.add(button);

        frame.add(pane);

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Now you have an output similar to this one:

[image]

What about you want the `JTextField` to have a more "normal" size? Like this one:

[image]

You'll have to embed `field` inside another `JPanel` (with `FlowLayout` (the default layout manager of `JPanel`)), and then add that second `JPanel` to `pane`, I'm not writing the code for that as I'm leaving that as an exercise to you so you learn how to use multiple layout managers