# Android - Draw an inverted circle that moves along with the player

Tags: android, geometry, android-canvas, shadow

I am building an Android game where a ball is controlled and moved using the motion sensor.

There are some posts on how to draw an inverted circle [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551035/draw-transparent-circle-filled-outside), but it is unusable as Android does not support BufferedImage.

I created the player using the codes below

```
public class Player extends Task {
    private final static float MAX_SPEED = 20;
    private final static float SIZE = 16;
    private Circle _cir = null;
    private Paint _paint = new Paint();
    private Vec _vec     = new Vec();
    private Vec _sensorVec = new Vec();

    public Player(){
        _cir = new Circle( 15, 15, SIZE ); //15,15 is the initial x,y coordinates
    }
    public final Circle getPt(){
        return _cir;
    }
    private void setVec(){
        float x = -AcSensor.Inst().getX()*2;
        float y =  AcSensor.Inst().getY()*2;
        _sensorVec._x = x < 0 ? -x*x : x*x;
        _sensorVec._y = y < 0 ? -y*y : y*y;
        _sensorVec.setLengthCap(MAX_SPEED);
        _vec.blend( _sensorVec, 0.05f );
    }
    private void Move(){
        _cir._x += _vec._x;
        _cir._y += _vec._y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUpdate(){
        setVec();
        Move();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw( Canvas c ){
        c.drawCircle(_cir._x, _cir._y, _cir._r, _paint);
    }

}
```

Question is, how to create an inverted circle around the player so that the player only sees a limited distance while the outer part is filled with black color? For example, something like this:
[image].