# Android - Google Maps inside CircleView

Tags: android, google-maps, android-canvas, android-custom-view, android-maps-v2

I wanted to show map inside a circle view where circle's outside area filled with a color. I referred a post [Draw transparent circle filled outside](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30292462/2032561). But now the problem is touch events. Map can be touched through outside circle view while I need map can be touched (zoom or move) only form inside Circle view (where the map is visible).

What I tried,

1. setEnabled=false
2. clickable=false

but still map is touched from outside circle view.

Is that possible to achieve that map can be touched from inside circle view.

```
public class RadiusOverlayView extends LinearLayout {
    private Bitmap windowFrame;

    public RadiusOverlayView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RadiusOverlayView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RadiusOverlayView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public RadiusOverlayView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

        if (windowFrame == null) {
            createWindowFrame(); // Lazy creation of the window frame, this is needed as we don't know the width & height of the screen until draw time
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(windowFrame, 0, 0, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isClickable() {
        return false;
    }

    protected void createWindowFrame() {
        windowFrame = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Create a new image we will draw over the map
        Canvas osCanvas = new Canvas(windowFrame); // Create a   canvas to draw onto the new image

        RectF outerRectangle = new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG); // Anti alias allows for smooth corners
        paint.setColor(Color.CYAN); // This is the color of your activity background
        osCanvas.drawRect(outerRectangle, paint);

        //paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); // An obvious color to help debugging
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT)); // A out B http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Alpha_compositing.svg
        float centerX = getWidth() / 2;
        float centerY = getHeight() / 2;
        float radius = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) / 2 - 50;
        osCanvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInEditMode() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        windowFrame = null; // If the layout changes null our frame so it can be recreated with the new width and height
    }
}
```

**XML layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
    <!--loading map in container-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <mypackage.RadiusOverlayView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Result:
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a `View.OnTouchListener` to your `RadiusOverlayView` and calculate whether the `RadiusOverlayView` needs to manage the touch events or not.
In this example I calculate this by testing if the `RadiusOverlayView` color touched is != 0 (maybe you want to improve this):

```
final RadiusOverlayView radiusOverlayView = (RadiusOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.radiusView);
radiusOverlayView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        return bmp.getPixel((int) motionEvent.getX(), (int) motionEvent.getY()) != 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: Just clarify, If I return false always its not suppose to move Right?

Comment: No, if you always return true the map will not move. Returning true means that the RadiusOverlayView's listener has consumed the event avoiding it from being propagated to the map.

Comment: Ya this logic works. The only hard thing is find x y (round shape) of inside/outside of the circle and return boolean value. Can you give any glimpse of that so that I can make sure touch happened outside the circle area.

Comment: The color check of my example is not enough?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I didn't understand the return value but now I do.. It works good.