# Custom, Disabled and Blank Map in android

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I want to display only the radius part of marker on map and rest of the map must be blank.
Like if Marker radius is 5 KM and i want that only that radius part of the map must be visible to user and rest of the map must be blank.

I have read about Google Map Overlays and also search about various SDK Like MapBox and Skobbler but none of them provide the functionality that i want.

[image: Here is the image which will explain how i want the map look like.]

In the image you can see that only some part around the marker is visible and rest is blank. I want to achieve this functionality in android Maps.

If anyone has any solution or idea, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: If you need a circle, this answer is exactly what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45525627/3604955

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `View` over the map that hides it and draw a circle on it to show only the desired locations.

I have based my answers on

- [Draw transparent circle filled outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551035/draw-transparent-circle-filled-outside/30292462#30292462)
- [Android - Google Maps inside CircleView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647057/android-google-maps-inside-circleview/35648839#35648839)
- [How can I draw a static target circle on Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737054/how-can-i-draw-a-static-target-circle-on-google-maps/35751087#35751087)

MapsActivity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private HideOverlayView hideView;
    private List<Marker> visibleMarkers = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        hideView = (HideOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.hideview);

        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            final SupportMapFragment f = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(this);

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(
                CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(new LatLng(40.22861, -3.95567), 15)));

        visibleMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(40.22861, -3.95567))));
        visibleMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(40.22977, -3.95338))));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(final CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
        List<Point> visiblePoints = new ArrayList<>();
        Projection projection = mMap.getProjection();

        for (Marker visibleMarker : visibleMarkers) {
            visiblePoints.add(projection.toScreenLocation(visibleMarker.getPosition()));
        }

        float radius = 150f; // meters
        Point centerPoint = projection.toScreenLocation(cameraPosition.target);
        Point radiusPoint = projection.toScreenLocation(
                SphericalUtil.computeOffset(cameraPosition.target, radius, 90));

        float radiusPx = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(centerPoint.x - radiusPoint.x, 2));

        hideView.reDraw(visiblePoints, radiusPx);
    }
}
```

HideOverlayView:

```
public class HideOverlayView extends LinearLayout {
    private Bitmap windowFrame;
    private float radius = 0f;
    private List<Point> points;

    public HideOverlayView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public HideOverlayView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

        createWindowFrame();
        canvas.drawBitmap(windowFrame, 0, 0, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isClickable() {
        return false;
    }

    public void reDraw(List<Point> points, float radius) {
        this.points = points;
        this.radius = radius;

        invalidate();
    }

    protected void createWindowFrame() {
        windowFrame = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas osCanvas = new Canvas(windowFrame);

        RectF outerRectangle = new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        osCanvas.drawRect(outerRectangle, paint);

        if (radius > 0 && points != null) {
            for (Point point : points) {
                paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT));
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                osCanvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, radius, paint);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInEditMode() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        windowFrame = null;
    }
}
```

activity_maps.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="mypackage.MySupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"/>
    <mypackage.HideOverlayView
        android:id="@+id/hideview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:radius="150dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Limitations:**

- This solution only updates the `HideOverlayView` on `onCameraChange`, so when the user zooms or pans the map, other locations on the map can be shown
- The calculations made to compute the radius don't take into account rotations and tilts of the map