# why remove fillcolor of polygon google map v2 android in zoom

Tags: android, google-maps, polygon

i add two polygon to google map and set fill color to them.
my problem is that fill color of polygon be removed when I am zoom the map ... 
what is solution ? 
my code is below :

```
polygonTrafic = googleMap.addPolygon(rectOptions);
    polygonTrafic.setFillColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
    polygonTrafic.setStrokeWidth(0);
```

Comment: There is a known open bug. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41398250/android-google-maps-polygon-or-shape-that-hides-entire-map/41398840#comment70007294_41398840

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: @jompi no, i dont