# Android Google map circle

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a map with many markers for places. I want to draw an overlay around all map with a black transparent color, and a circle around those markers which is fully transparent to show them. Like the attached picture.

I know how to add an overlay view, but I don't know how to add the middle circle while keeping the overlay colored.

If I use `Circle` then only the circle is colored, and not rest of map.

I also tried to draw something like this but yea won't work ^^.

```
        int d = 500; // diameter
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(d, d, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        c.drawCircle(d / 2, d / 2, d / 2, p);

        // generate BitmapDescriptor from circle Bitmap
        BitmapDescriptor bmD = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bm);

        // mapView is the GoogleMap
        googleMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions().
                image(bmD).
                position(latLng, RADIUS_CIRCLE * 2, RADIUS_CIRCLE * 2).
                transparency(0.4f));
```

I am confused and not sure how to work it out. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

[image: Black view with transparent circle inside it]

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030648/custom-disabled-and-blank-map-in-android/36039979#36039979

Comment: @antonio Thank you, that is what I have been looking for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551035/draw-transparent-circle-filled-outside/30292462#30292462

Answer (score 0):

Please check Antonio's answer in the comments. I have tested that and works for me.
user1892172 answer but i didn't test it, but seems correct also.
Thanks.